# disable autocorrect in a div or pre tag within a UIWebView

Tags: html, uiwebview, autocomplete, spell-checking, pre

Hi I'm working on an iOS web app.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to disable autocorrect/autocapitalize/spellcheck on  a pre element.  My HTML looks like this.

```
<pre id="codePre" class="prettyprint" contenteditable="true"  > Some test to edit </pre>
```

Setting autococorrect/autocapitalize/spellcheck attributes has NO effect (these seem to be only for form and input elements).  Are there any ways to go about this at the html level or using objective C (like acting directly on the UIWebView or otherwise)?  Are there user defaults I can set that would kill this unneeded 'feature'?

Comment: Have you figured it out yet? If you did, please post your solution, I'm having the same problem

Comment: Have you solved this issue? As by searching,i came to know that it is not possible as safari mobile browser doesn't support autocorrection and spellcheck.Please provide solution if you have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a tad long, but it might help to have at least 1 proposed solution. Try adding `autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"` to any element where you don't want auto-correct turned on. Works on the latest Chrome and Firefox, unsure about Mobile Safari.